# Increment/decrement quantity on button click using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel-5, axios

Attempting to use JavaScript to increment/decrement quantity on button click.

JavaScript was already written (and works) whereby a new value can be inputted into the text field and the value in the text field reflects the new value and the total updates (based on price * quantity).

Script for the aforementioned:

```
<script>
  (function() {
    const className = document.querySelectorAll('.quantity-no')

    Array.from(className).forEach(function(element) {
      element.addEventListener('change', function() {
        const id = element.getAttribute('data-id')

        axios.patch(`/cart/${id}`, {
          quantity: this.value
        })

        .then(function (response) {
          // console.log(response);
          window.location.href = '{{ route('cart.index') }}'
        })

        .catch(function (error) {
          // console.log(error);
          window.location.href = '{{ route('cart.index') }}'
        });
      })
    })
  })();
</script>
```

The increment/decrement buttons update the value in the text field, but the change in quantity is not reflected in the total (based on price * quantity).

Code for the aforementioned:

```
<script>
  function decrementQuantity(qty, rowId) {
    var inputQuantityNo = $('.quantity-no' + rowId);
    var newQuantity = parseInt($(inputQuantityNo).val()) - 1;

    axios.patch(`/cart/${id}`, {
      quantity: newQuantity.value
    })

    .then(function (response) {
      window.location.href = '{{ route('cart.index') }}'
    })

    .catch(function (error) {
      window.location.href = '{{ route('cart.index') }}'
    });
  }
</script>
```

I haven't bothered trying to write the script for the increment.

Here is the other applicable code:

```
<div class="col-2">
 <div class="quantity d-flex align-items-center">
  <div class="dec-btn" onclick="decrementQuantity($item->qty, $item->rowId)"> - </div>
  <input type="text" value="{{ $item->qty }}" class="quantity-no" data-id="{{ $item->rowId }}">
  <div class="inc-btn" onclick="incrementQuantity($item->qty, $item->rowId"> + </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `newQuantity` appears to be a number - please test if using `quantity: newQuantity` instead of `quantity: newQuantity.value` in the `axios.patch` call (in `decrementQuantity`) works any better - I have absolutely no way of testing the code.

Comment: Hi, attempted that change with no luck, so I'm thinking that when the increment/decrement button is clicked, it's not updating the quantity value and therefore the page is not getting updated.